# How can I get the SNS topic ARN using the topic name to publish a SNS message in Python via Boto3?

Tags: python, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-sns

Python

method to run query

```
def function(run_query)
   //topic = arn return from topic name
   topic.publish(message)
   pass
```

I am using the boto3 resource method. There are lot of examples of using boto3.client and limited example of sns method implementation using boto3 resource methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to be no easy, expected `get_topic_arn(topic_name)` method to get an AWS topic ARN using the topic name, via the Boto3 SNS client or resource.

However, a clever workaround would be to use the [`create_topic`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.ServiceResource.create_topic) method:

> This action is **idempotent**, so if the requester **already owns a topic with the specified name**, that **topic's ARN is returned** without creating a new topic.

**Call `create_topic` with an existing topic name, which will retrieve the [`SNS.Topic`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Topic) sub-resource, and then call the [`publish`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Topic.publish) method on the topic sub-resource.**

```py
import boto3

sns = boto3.resource('sns')

topic = sns.create_topic(Name='MyTopicName')
topic_arn = topic.arn

response = topic.publish(Message='MyMessage')
...
```

Comment: This is how I am using in my current work. And I was wondering if there is any other better way, or this is the efficient way. Thank you for your input too, it gives me confidence in using this method as solution.

Comment: What if you don't want to create the topic, just query if it exists?

Comment: @AaronLelevier That's a separate question, this is regarding getting the ARN of an existing queue - feel free to open an SO question and tag me here. I just don't want to clutter the comments!

Comment: I been googling and also looking the boto3 documentation and I did not see a method to get the topic by name. I end up with this solution.

Comment: This requires a CreateTopic permission, which can be overly permissive